# Creating a named CMYK swatch with specific properties to enable contour cutting

Tags: inkscape

When creating images/text in Illustrator ready to be exported (eps, AI or pdf) to enable me to print & contour cut on my vinyl printer, I have to take the following steps in Illustrator to create the cut contour:

a. Create the shape, and select "No fill".

b. Select "stroke", and open the fill & stroke window.

c. Using CMYK, colour the stroke as 100% magenta.

d. Select "create swatch" and create a new SPOT colour, which must be named "CutContour"; set the stroke width to 0.25mm, and the mitre limit to 1.

I am new to Inkscape, but I can see that I can set the stroke width and the mitre limit, and I can use "stroke paint" to colour the stroke as 100% magenta as a CMYK colour. However, I cannot see where to (a.) set the colour as a SPOT colour, or (b.) give the newly created colour a NAME (which is vital if the print & cut software is going to recognise it as a cut line).

Can anybody help please?

Much obliged!

**Steve**

Answer (score 3):

Inkscape doesn't have support for CMYK, even though you can mix Cyan, Magenta, Yellow and Black to get RGB colors.

If you want to use named colors and export a CMYK pdf, create your SVG in Inkscape, then import it into Scribus, name the color and choose to export a pdf intended 'for printer'.

Comment: This led me in the right direction. The next step is covered by: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56261156/scribus-spot-color-pdf